# How to place all row items in one line equally? Flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to place all row items equally in one line, exactly like what **align-Item : center** does in html.

My project piece is the image below, but the image is not aligned with the buttons.
And the buttons are a little higher than the picture.

> And my codes :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Spacer(),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: (() {}),
                child: Text("Report"),
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    backgroundColor: Color(0xffffb200),
                    foregroundColor: Color(0xff00324B)),
              ),
              Spacer(),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: (() {}),
                child: Text("Donate"),
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    backgroundColor: Color(0xffffb200),
                    foregroundColor: Color(0xff00324B)),
              ),
              Spacer(),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: (() {}),
                child: Text("Adopt"),
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    backgroundColor: Color(0xffffb200),
                    foregroundColor: Color(0xff00324B)),
              ),
              Spacer(),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 30, 0, 10),
                height: 60.0,
                width: 60.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(95),
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage("assets/images/download.jpg"),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 14,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I even tried **mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center**

and **crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center** but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 30, 0, 10),` from your last element of Row

```
 Container(
           // margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 30, 0, 10),
            height: 60.0,
            width: 60.0,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(95),
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage("assets/images/download.jpg"),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: Thank you. I did not pay attention to it :)))))

Answer (score 0):

you can just add in the Row`

```
Row(
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
)
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work :(

Comment: I think the problem is in the image. Center of the image must be the center of the circle

Answer (score 0):

You should use crossAxisAlignment to align the row. So like this

```
    Row(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center)
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work -_-